# Nginx redirect to main domain from subdomain without changing URL in address bar

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I have a domain and wildcard subdomains.

```
main domain: example.com
subdomains: s1.example.com, s2.example.com etc.
```

Now the requirements is

> `s1.example.com` will be redirect to `example.com/organization/s1`
>
> `s2.example.com` will be redirect to `example.com/organization/s2`

and For `s1.example.com` or `s2.example.com` my configuration is:

```
    upstream frontend {
       server example.com;
    }  

    server_name ~^(?<name>.+)\.example\.com$;

    location / {

    proxy_pass http://frontend;
    rewrite ^/$ /organization/$name break;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Now I am not sure what i am missing in my config.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested):

```
  server_name: *.example.com
    location / { 
        if ($host ~* (.*)\.domain\.com) {
            set $sub_domain $1;
            return 301 $scheme://example.com/organization/$sub_domain;
        }
    }
```

or using rewrite:

```
  server_name *.example.com;
  set $subdomain $1;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://example.com/organization/$1;
```

I think it's better to separate the config of the subdomain (*.example.com) and the main domain (example.com). If you separate it you should not use `proxy_pass` in the subdomain because the config is only for redirection without content.

Comment: It's working. But It's redirecting. I don't want to change url in address bar.

Comment: If you don't want change URL don't use redirect, and you should handle on your application (PHP or nodejs)